# How do I turn light the oven pilot on this vintage stove?

Tags: oven, stove, antique

My 30s Wedgewood stove has an oven pilot that is funky. I distinctly recall that I had to do something special to light the oven pilot last time I shut the gas off, but I can't remember what it was. At the time, we had just

The right third of the oven had a trash/wood burner, there's an apparatus in there with a red button:

[image: Full view]

I do recall that the red button was involved in relighting the pilot:

[image: Switch]

But that's all I recall. I tried holding it down but that didn't seem to help. This is where I think the pilot is:

[image: rear of oven]

Note that my view isn't nearly so clear, but I could stick my phone back there. Am I even lighting the right thing?

Does anyone actually know how to light this oven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this wasn't hard. I called the stove repair company and they talked me through it:

The pilot just lights (no idea why it wasn't coming on the first few times I tried it) and then I had to depress and release the red reset button before the oven would actually work.

Comment: You told us you did it but you did not tell us how. Perhaps you could amend your answer to explain the procedure the repair company had you do so others who find this "answer"  while searching for an answer to a similar problem can learn.

Comment: Fixed the punctuation, hope that's more clear?

Answer (score 0):

The little piece in the far back end of the photo (the one she thinks is the pilot light), IS the pilot light.  You can light it manually with a match or lighter. If the stove is getting gas, it should light.

Once the pilot light is lit, when you turn on the oven, the burner might not get gas and ignite right away.

Press and release that red button and few times and it comes on.
That’s what worked for me anyway.
Not sure why. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Just did this myself. I was looking near the red button for the pilot but you have to pull out the broiler drawer to get to it. It’s not on the side like the red button is. It’s behind the broiler drawer.